# Error signing certificate

Tags: debian, openssl, certificates

I am trying to create and sign a certificate for Email services. Using [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html).
Everything went well until i reached :

```
sudo openssl ca -in server.csr -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

After entering the passphrase i got this error!

```
rootserver1:/home/i*******i# sudo openssl ca —in server.csr —config /etc/ssl/open
ssl. cnf
Using configuration from /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
Enter pass phrase for /etc/ssl/private/cakey.pem:
/etc/ssl/CA/serial: No such file or directory
error while loading serial number
140270S345831S4:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bs
s_file.c:398:fopen(’/etc/ssl/CA/serial’,’r’)
140270S345S3184:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
```

`/etc/ssl/CA/serial` does exist and contains `01` as instructed in the above mentioned tutorials.
My system is a Debian 8.2 running in a VPS service.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found the answer.

The article i was using was rock solid! 
The problem was in Common Name,known today as FQDN (fully qualified domain name).
The `Hostname: s1.MySite.com` and `server1.MySite.com` difference made a huge impact!

While editing the certificate, country, business name and such.. FQDN has to be very specifically as registered. Not as the `hostname` in the machine (if it is different).

In my VPS installation the command :
`me***# hostname` will return 
`server1`. My site is sitting on `server1.MySite.com`. In the hosting service however ,in the SolusVm Control Panel, i have :

```
Hostname : s1.MySite.com
```

It just turned out that was the way i registered it.

Still i am not sure what kind of further trouble i might get into because of this...